# Confusion applying the shifting property of z-transform

Tags: z-transform

I'd like to calculate the z-transform of $Z=(-3)^{-n}u[n-2]=\left(-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^nu[n-2]$. Also, I'd like to use shifting property, which states:
$$x(n-k)\rightarrow z^{-k}\left(X(z)+\sum_{n=1}^kx(-n)z^k\right)$$
For the function in question, that would be:
$$\left(-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^nu[n-2] \rightarrow z^{-2}\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{z^{-1}}{3}}-3z+9z^2\right)$$
After some simplification $Z=\dfrac{3}{3z^2+z}-\dfrac{3}{z}+9$. After further simplification verified [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/algebra-calculator/simplify%20x%5E%7B-2%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5Ccdot3%7D%7D-3%5Ccdot%20x%2B9%5Ccdot%20x%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright)), it becomes $Z=\dfrac{27z}{3z+1}$. However, [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%20transform&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22ZTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22transformfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%28-1%2F3%29%5E%28n%29UnitStep%28n-2%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22ZTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22variable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22n%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22z%20transform%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22ZTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22variable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22z%22) gives a different transform, which is $\dfrac{1}{9z^2+3z}$. So, I am confused. How should one apply the shifting property? what if the function were $\left(-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{n-2}u[n-2]$, or more generally $a^{n-k}u[n-j]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are two versions of $\mathcal{Z}$-transform. The bilateral $\mathcal{Z}$-transform is defined as $$X(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x[n]z^{-n}$$And the unilateral $\mathcal{Z}$-transform is defined as $$X(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x[n]z^{-n}$$Adopting the bilateral transform, yields $$\mathcal{Z}\{\alpha^nu[n]\} = \frac{1}{1-\alpha z^{-1}} \\ \mathcal{Z}\{x[n-n_0]\} = z^{-n_0}X(z)$$
Combining these facts, we have $$\mathcal{Z}\{(-\dfrac{1}{3})^{n-2}u[n-2] \} =  \frac{z^{-2}}{1+\frac{z^{-1}}{3} } \implies \\ \mathcal{Z}\{(-\dfrac{1}{3})^{n}u[n-2] \} = \frac{z^{-2}}{9+3z^{-1} } = \frac{1}{9z^2 +3z} = \frac{1}{3z(3z+1)}$$ This can be easily verified by [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28-1%2F3%29%5En*%28theta%28n-2%29%29z%5E%28-n%29%20from%20n%20%3D%20-infty%20to%20infty). Also read [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ZTransform.html) documentation which mentions WA computes the unilateral transform by default. The unilateral transform gives $$\mathcal{Z}\{\alpha^nu[n]\} = \frac{1}{1-\alpha z^{-1}} \tag{1}$$ $$\mathcal{Z}\{x[n-1]\} = z^{-1}X(z) + x[-1] \implies \mathcal{Z}\{x[n-2]\} = x[-2] + x[-1]z^{-1} + z^{-2}X(z) \tag{2}$$
By choosing $\alpha=\frac{-1}{3}$ in equation $(1)$, we have $$\mathcal{Z}\{(-\frac{1}{3})^nu[n]\} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{z^{-1}}{3}}$$Now let $x[n] =  (-\frac{1}{3})^nu[n]$, so we have $x[-1] = x[-2] = 0$ which implies, by equation $(2)$, $$\mathcal{Z}\{(-\frac{1}{3})^{n-2}u[n-2]\} = z^{-2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{z^{-1}}{3}}$$
Finally, by linearity property we have $$\mathcal{Z}\{(-\frac{1}{3})^{n}u[n-2]\} = \frac{z^{-2}}{9}\frac{1}{1+\frac{z^{-1}}{3}}$$
In this case both transforms give the same result since $(-\dfrac{1}{3})^{n}u[n] = 0$ for $n\lt0$.

Comment: I used the unilateral transform. In particular, I used $x[-2]+x[-1]z^{-1}+z^{-2}X(z)$. However, I got a different expression. I guess my question would be: what is $x[-2],x[-1],$ and $X(z)$, because I suspect that's what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Schach21 I couldn't understand your solution but make sure that you are applying equation $(2)$ to equation $(1)$ correctly. In applying equation equation $(2)$, we should replace $n$ by $n-2$ in every occurrence of $n$ .

Comment: @Schach21 I added the details of the derivation.

Comment: That was my issue. I was not replacing $n-2$ in every occurrence of $n$. Thank you very much!